# Collect signature in-person using Adobe Sign

Tags: adobe-sign

I have a use case where I want to allow customers visiting our Customer Service Department to fill out and sign forms using Adobe Sign.

Customers will be given a community iPad, and they need to enter their personal information, sign the form and leave the iPad for the next person to do the same.

I'm struggling with getting this working the way I want using Adobe Web Forms and was wondering if anyone had any success doing the same with Adobe Sign and how you did it.